# How To Create A Right And Left Aligned Staircase With #s THAT ARE SIDE BY SIDE in C

Tags: c, printf

I am trying to create something that looks a little like this:

[mario stairs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFAz2.png)

I know how to create them individually but I cant sort out how to make them side by side...
my code is below all in main of course

```
int answer = get_int("Height: ");

while( answer < 1 || answer > 8){
    answer = get_int("Height: ");

}

int column = answer -1;

for(int i = 1; i <=answer; i++){
    for(int j = 1; j <= column; j++){
        printf(" ");
    }
    column--;
    for(int k = 1; k <= i ; k++){
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
}

for(int a = 1; a <=answer; a++){
    for(int b = 1; b <=a; b++){
        printf("#");
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

}

and the output is like this

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xKPAy.png)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your code as it is missing some key elements in order to compile (where is `main`? what is `get_int`?).

However, this is my approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define HEIGHT 6

void print_whitespace(int n){printf("%*c", n, ' ');}
void print_hash(int n){while(n--) printf("#");}

int main(void) {
    for(int h = 1; h < HEIGHT ; h++)
    {
        print_whitespace(HEIGHT - h); // left side whitespaces
        print_hash(offset);           // left side '#'
        print_whitespace(1);          // center whitespace
        print_hash(offset);           // right side '#'
        print_whitespace(HEIGHT - h); // right side whitespaces
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: get int is the first line of code and I started above that the code was inside the main but i did not include the main

Answer (score 0):

You need to combine your top and bottom loops into one:

1. First print left whitespace.
2. Then print left side of pyramid/triangle
3. Print the separater
4. Print the right side of the triangle
5. Print a newline.

Repeat the above for the number of lines you want.

---

Here is the cleaned up and corrected code. Note that I changed it to take the count from the first program argument (e.g. `./mypgm 4`) for [my] ease of debugging:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int answer;

    --argc;
    ++argv;

    if (argc != 1)
        exit(1);

    answer = atoi(*argv);

    int column = answer - 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= answer; i++) {
        // print left margin
        for (int j = 1; j <= column; j++)
            printf(" ");

        // print left pyramid
        for (int k = 1; k <= i; k++)
            printf("#");

        // print separater
        printf(" ");

        // print right pyramid
        for (int a = 1; a <= i; a++)
            printf("#");

        column--;

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is what I was looking for

Answer (score 0):

The width and precison fields of the `%s` specifier can be used to print the image.
The width field will print at least the desired number of characters and the precision field will print up to the desired number of characters. Values can be used in the specifier or an asterisk can be used to get a value from the arguments.
Entering the number of times to repeat the line determines the width of the field for the left side. In each iteration, the precision is increased for the number of characters to print within the field.
The right side only needs to print the same number of characters as the left side.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 8

int main( void) {
    char hash[SIZE + 1] = { [0 ... SIZE] '#'};
    char input[100] = "";
    int repeat = 0;
    int result = 0;

    do {
        printf ( "input height [1 to %d]\n", SIZE);
        if ( fgets ( input, sizeof input, stdin)) {//get a line
            result = sscanf ( input, "%d", &repeat);//try to scan an integer
        }
        else {
            fprintf ( stderr, "fgets EOF\n");
            return 0;
        }
    } while ( 1 != result || repeat <= 0 || repeat > SIZE);

    for ( int each = 0; each < repeat; ++each) {
        printf ( "%*.*s %.*s\n", repeat, each + 1, hash, each + 1, hash);
    }

    return 0;
}
```